# Como deixar um número sempre negativo no php?

Tags: php

Tenho uma classificação "A" e "B". Se for "A", quero que o número sempre seja positivo, se for "B" quero que sempre seja negativo.

Estou usando um código nesta lógica:

```
if($classificacao==="A") 
    $sinal="abs";
elseif($classificacao==="B") 
    $sinal="-1*abs";
```

E o número é escrito da forma: `$valor_final = $sinal($valor);`

Porém, ao fazer desta forma, origina o seguinte erro:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function -1*abs()".

Ele reconhece como se `-1*abs` fosse uma função não existente. Já para o caso da classificação "A" está funcionando. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Parece-me ser uma solução bem deselegante e não funciona justamente pelo motivo que o erro diz: o PHP tentará interpretar o valor `-1*abs` como o nome da função. Não só não existirá a função como é um nome inválido. Daria para utilizar o `eval`, mas fica tão ruim quanto e é completamente desnecessário.

A solução mais simples que eu vejo para o seu problema é definir apenas o multiplicador dentro do `if`:

```
if ($classificacao === "A") {
    $sinal = 1;
} else {
    $sinal = -1;
}
```

> **Nota:** se você possui apenas duas classificações, não precisa verificar se o valor é igual a B quando é diferente de A.

E exibir o resultado da seguinte forma:

```
$valor_final = $sinal * abs($valor);
```

Obviamente que existem muitas variações deste código que produzem o mesmo resultado. Por exemplo:

```
$valor_final = abs($valor);

if ($classificacao === "B") {
    $valor_final *= -1;
}
```

---

Dado a existência da classificação C, como dito nos comentários, que deve manter o valor original, pode ser feito algo como:

```
function valueByClassification ($valor, $classificacao) {

    if ($classificacao === 'C') {

        $valor_final = $valor;

    } else {

        $valor_final = abs($valor);

        if ($classificacao === 'B') {
            $valor_final *= -1;
        }

    }

    return $valor_final;
}
```

Eu considero esta forma a melhor pois você utiliza apenas uma vez a função `abs` no código. Em questão de desempenho não faz diferença, mas em questão de manutenção de código fica melhor, pois se houver a necessidade de alterar a função chamada, precisa fazer isto em apenas uma parte do código, não em várias.

Veja o teste da função abaixo:

```
$tests = [
    // {valor}        {classificacao}        {esperado}
    [    5,                  'A',                5     ],    
    [   -3,                  'A',                3     ],
    [    0,                  'A',                0     ],    

    [    5,                  'B',               -5     ],    
    [   -3,                  'B',               -3     ],    
    [    0,                  'B',                0     ],    

    [    5,                  'C',                5     ],    
    [   -3,                  'C',               -3     ],    
    [    0,                  'C',                0     ],    
];

foreach($tests as $i => $test) {
    list($valor, $classificacao, $esperado) = $test;

    $obtido = valueByClassification($valor, $classificacao);

    if ($obtido === $esperado) {
        echo "Teste $i foi aprovado.", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Teste $i foi reprovado. Era esperado {$esperado}, mas foi obtido {$obtido}.", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/HQWtUL).

A saída gerada é:

```
Teste 0 foi aprovado.
Teste 1 foi aprovado.
Teste 2 foi aprovado.
Teste 3 foi aprovado.
Teste 4 foi aprovado.
Teste 5 foi aprovado.
Teste 6 foi aprovado.
Teste 7 foi aprovado.
Teste 8 foi aprovado.
```

Comment: Me precipitei na pergunta,existe no meu caso uma classificação "C" em que ele deixaria o valor original,por isso não consegui colocar o "abs" fora da variável "$sinal". Mas com a utilização da função sugerida,consegui resolver o problema! Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Eu reesolveria seu código com esta função:

```
function myFunction($classificacao, $valor){
    if($classificacao==="A") 
        $valor_final = abs($valor);
    elseif($classificacao==="B") 
        $valor_final = abs($valor)*(-1);

    return $valor_final;
}
```